# Retrieve the last user only who reviewed a post

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

What I am trying to do here is query the last user reviewed a business.

**This is biz table**

---

id | username | bizname | city_id
----------------------------------.......

**This is review table**

---

id | bisid | username | content
----------------------------------......

The code is working fine, but at the end I realized of 10 users review one business then my homepage is all about that business.

**EX:** 
Let say I have three business' on my website.  MC Donald' , Jimmy Johns a KFC

I want to show the last user reviewed that business.

I want it to be like:

Mike reviewed MC Donald

Steve reviewed Jimmy Johns

Dave reviewed KFC

Instead of:

Mike reviewed MC Donald 
Jaycee reviewed MC Donald 
Anna reviewed MC Donald 
John reviewed MC Donald 
Jose reviewed MC Donald 
Steve reviewed Jimmy Johns
Dave reviewed KFC

```
 Class Local extends CI_controller {

   public function city() {

      $data['reviews'] = $this->reviews->get_city_reviews($city->id,10,0);

      $this->load->view('local/index',$data);

   }

 }
```

The model

```
 Class Reviews extends MY_model {

public function get_city_reviews($city_id,$limit,$offset)
{
    $list = array();
    $this->db->select('review.*');
    $this->db->from('review');
    $this->db->join('biz','biz.id = review.bizid');
    $this->db->where('biz.city_id',$city_id);
    $this->db->order_by('review.created_at','desc');
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $list[] = $row;
    }
    return $list;
}

  }
```

Comment: Try doing a `limit(1)` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

```
public function get_city_reviews($city_id,$limit,$offset)
{
    $list = array();

    $this->db->from('review');
    $this->db->join('biz','biz.id = review.bizid');
    $this->db->where('biz.city_id',$city_id);
    $this->db->order_by('review.created_at','desc');
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
            $this->db->group_by('bizid');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $list[] = $row;
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting DISTINCT bisid when querying the reviews table

EDIT: Here's an example http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: If I use DISTINCT then I am gonna have issue fetching other data from REVIEW TABLE, like getting review.content, review.username....